# Add three Buttons in an UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created uialertview, and add two buttons, Now I need to add one more button in alert view. How to edit my code to add one more button?

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Refresh" message:@"Are you want to Refresh Data" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are really struggling to find the solution, the following code may help you.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:@"Refresh" 
                              message:@"Are you want to Refresh Data" 
                             delegate:self 
                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                    otherButtonTitles:@"OK", @"Done", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: if u want to touch , get an iphone or probably an ipod touch

Comment: UIAlertView deprecated in iOS 9.0. Please use UIAlertController.

Answer (score 11):

You can also make your class the delegate of UIAlertViewDelegate and reach all of your buttons" functionalities by doing so;

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        //
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In iOS11 / Swift 4, it is as simple as this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saving Demo.", message: "Do you wish to save this Demo Settings?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
                (_)in
                //SAVE DEMO DATA HERE       
            })
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
                (_)in
                //do something
            })
            let thirdAction = UIAlertAction(title: "3rd Btn", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
                (_)in
                //do another thing
            })
            alert.addAction(OKAction)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            alert.addAction(thirdAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add your buttons in otherButtonTitles

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Refresh" message:@"Are you want to Refresh Data" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Button1",@"Button2"@"Button2",nil];
```

Comment: hi BuildSucceeded, Thanks for your reply. Really it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"Refresh"
                              message:@"Are you want to Refresh Data" 
                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             // code here...
                         }];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             // code here...
                         }];

UIAlertAction* done = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Done"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             // code here...
                         }];

[alert addAction:ok] ;
[alert addAction:done];
[alert addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Answer (score 0):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title",
                                      message: "message",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restore Purchases", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in

            //function to execute when button is clicked

        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Subscribe", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in

            //function to execute when button is clicked

        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in

            //function to execute when button is clicked
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```